# How can I get the contents of a Jenkins job's Build Log in "Post-Build Actions"?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins version 2.375.1 that runs a particular job.

During the "Build Steps" portion of the job, a URL is printed to the execution console (build log).  I am trying to pull that URL from the build log in order to add the URL to my post-build emails (Editable Email Notification).

How can I get the contents of the Build Log at this point?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example to extract a string using regex in your post steps.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo "something else"
                echo 'my_url="https://google.com"'
                echo "something else"
            }

            post {
                success {
                    script {
                        def consoleLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text
                        // THis would extract "123456" from the console output my_url="1234567"
                        def url = (consoleLog =~ 'my_url="(.*)"')[0][1]
                        echo "URL is: $url"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can this be translated to a freestyle/GUI job?  For example, can I still use `Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName(env.JOB_NAME).getBuildByNumber(Integer.parseInt(env.BUILD_NUMBER)).logFile.text`?

Comment: @Brian I'm not sure. Give it a try and see. Also you can try using a plugin like https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy-postbuild/ which allows you to access build elements.